# When a shortcut key is pressed focus on select tag using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, focus

I wanted my key shortcut (shift + c) to focus on the form's select tag when i press it like how tab works when its pressed.

In my html I have this form select tag

```html
<select id="myOptions">
  <option selected> Options</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

And here are the scripts that I tried to focus on the select tag but it does not work even in my console:

```
$document.on("keydown", function(event){
  if(event.shiftKey && event.keyCode === 67){
    angular.element(document.getElementById("myOptions")).focus()

    // a simple javascript does not focus it as well
    // document.getElementById("myOptions").focus()
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, using jQuery:

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode === 67) {
    document.getElementById("myOptions").focus();
  }
});
```

Note the `);` at the end, which you were missing.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put that, yes it works in jQuery but that's not the problem. I'm trying to do it the angular way. Is there any way I can do this?

in my controller I have this:

`function myController($scope, $socket, focus, $timeout, $filter, $interval, moment, $http,transformRequestAsFormPost, $document, Statistics)`

@ChrisG